# Issue with CSRF Filter Exclusion for Subdomain in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain, csrf, codeigniter-4

I'm currently facing an issue with excluding CSRF protection for a specific subdomain in my CodeIgniter 4 application.

**Problem Description:**
I have implemented a custom filter (NoCSRF) to exclude CSRF protection for the devapi subdomain, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. CSRF protection is still being enforced, causing issues with my API routes.

Code Implementation:
app/Filters/NoCSRF.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

class NoCSRF extends CSRF
{
   public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
   {
    // Get the host from the request
    $host = $request->getHeaderLine('host');
    
    // Extract subdomain
    $subdomain = explode('.', $host)[0];

    log_message('info', 'Request received from host: ' . $subdomain);

    // Do not apply CSRF protection for the devapi subdomain
    if ($subdomain === 'devapi') {
        return $request;
    }
    return parent::before($request, $arguments);
   }

   public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
   {
    return parent::after($request, $response, $arguments);
   }
}
```

1. I've verified that the NoCSRF filter is being executed by logging the host information, and it works as expected.
2. The CSRF filter is still enforcing protection for the devapi subdomain, even though the NoCSRF filter should exclude it.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or advice from the community on resolving this issue. If you have encountered a similar situation or have expertise with CSRF protection in CodeIgniter 4, your input would be invaluable.

Comment: You'll need to look in your `app/Config/Filters.php` as its probably still enabled there.